# Disable "Google Mail all mail" folders in Evolution

Tags: evolution

My gmail account is properly set up and shows a list of folders, Inbox, Drafts, etc. But it has an additional folder all [Google Mail] and in it I can see All Mail, Spam, etc. I want to disable it and disable the subscription to it so that it doesn't appear in the interface at all.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable certain IMAP folders in GMail, including the All Mail folder, if you enable the Google Labs "Advanced IMAP Controls".  From webmail:

1. Go to Settings > Labs and set "Advanced IMAP Controls" to "Enable"
2. Once advanced IMAP controls are enabled, you can go to Settings > Labels and uncheck the "Show in IMAP" box next to the folders you want to get rid of (All Mail, Spam, etc.).
3. Go back to Evolution and refresh the account, and the folders you unchecked will be gone.

Be warned that you lose functionality if you disable some of those folders, though. If you disable the spam folder, for example, then you can't train GMail's spam filter from Evolution, and disabling the "Trash" folder keeps you from being able to ever delete anything.

Comment: Is there a modern-day equivalent of this answer? The "Labs" tab is, of course, gone.

Comment: I think you can just skip the "labs" step and go directly to the labels tab.

Answer (score 0):

remove your account and follow [this tutorial](http://tuxicity.wordpress.com/2007/03/08/howto-set-up-gmail-in-evolution-gnomes-mail-client-and-organizer/), If you want to get only new email!
if you set server type to **IMAP** in **receiving email** step it will download your whole emails to evolution but if you set it to **POP** it only download new emails you receive

Comment: I took a look at that tutorial and it didn't help much :S I don't want to delete the account, I just want to hide that folder and make sure it doesn't update it unnecessarilly.

Comment: Go to **Edit > Preferences > Mail Accounts**, then press **edit**, on **Identity** tab uncheck the **Make this My default account** (if this not your only mail account), then on **receiving email** tab change server type to **pop**.I hope it can help you :)