# Disable “All Mail” folders in Evolution (on ProtonMail)

Tags: email, evolution

*// this post is similar to [this one about Gmail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11040/disable-google-mail-all-mail-folders-in-evolution) but this is a question about ProtonMail*

Hi,

ProtonMail uses an "All Mail" folder, which is just a copy of all email in every other folder.

In Evolution, this folder is treated as a "normal" one, meaning if I search for something I get duplicate search results: one in the folder the email is in and one in the "all mail" folder.

I'd like to disable the All Mail folder in Evolution completely... Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!
Andreas

Comment: What do you mean by "normal"?  How is your e-mail client connected?  POP3?  IMAP?  If you're connected by IMAP (typical these days) and your mail server serves duplicates of all of your e-mails, then unfortunately those copies are also going to come up when you search.  Because that's what your mail server says is there.  Unless you can disable this feature from your mail host/server, I'm doubtful that there is a way for the software to pretend they aren't there.

Comment: Thank you, I figured as much.. Yes via IMAP. If I find some other solution I'll post back